# python huge dictionary comparison

Tags: python, list, dictionary, optimization

I have two Dictionaries and a list as follows

```
list1 =[['3', {'3': ['4'], '10': ['2'], '9': ['8'], '11': ['8']}],
    ['8', {'7': ['8'], '6': ['9'], '3': ['1']}],
    ['7', {'5': ['11'], '10': ['6'], '2': ['3']}],
    ['9', {'4': ['1']}]
    ]
list2 ={0: -2.829363315837061, 1: -3.483150971596311, 2: -3.55866903680906, 3: -3.644673448138691, 4: -3.78, 5: -3.9343704669124677, 6: -4.1158785480167435, 7: -4.074895059134982, 8: -4.397225116848732, 9: -4.425674125747298, 10: -4.416164011466592, 11: -4.906491662382141}

list3 ={0: -2.865996006819783, 1: -3.6503055799900492, 2: -3.58670223884185, 3: -3.73129019873609, 4: -3.73, 5: -4.049442571308586, 6: -4.086222130931718, 7: -4.19022476024935, 8: -4.243919389901362, 9: -4.246976004644184, 10: -4.334028831306514, 11: -4.678255063114617}
```

I am trying to get the values associated with the key from the two dictionaries(list2 and list3) based on the keys in the list1 if the key are same and then multiply the values of  list2 which has same key as list one with the value of list1 and add those values for every list of dictionary in list1.same case with list 3 too.

```
for index in range(len(list1)):
tot_pos_probability = 0
tot_neg_probability =0
    for the_key, the_value in list1[index][1].items():
        for item in list2.keys():
            if int(the_key) == item:
                tot_pos_probability += int(the_value[0])*list2.get(item)
        for elem in list3.keys():
            if int(the_key) == elem:
                tot_neg_probability += int(the_value[0])*list3.get(elem)
```

The above code is working completely fine and giving me results as expected for the above list and dictionary example.

But My original list1 size is around 15000 and each dictionary inside list1 contain around 200-400 key value pair.Similarly the two dictionaries list2 and list3 also contain around 10000 unique key value pairs.The above code is working really poor in this case.I am not able to get any result.It keeps running for 10 minutes and no result.Could you please help me with an optimizing solution which work really good in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the inner `for` loops , in those you are simply checking if `the_key` is a key in list2 or `list3` and then using your formula to calculate `tot_pos_probability` and `tot_neg_probability` . You can instead use `.get()` with a default value of `0` , so that it does not change the probability if the `key` does not exist. Example -

```
for list1elem in list1:
    tot_pos_probability = 0
    tot_neg_probability =0
    for the_key, the_value in list1elem[1].items():
        tot_pos_probability += int(the_value[0])*list2.get(int(the_key), 0)
        tot_neg_probability += int(the_value[0])*list3.get(int(the_key), 0)
```

Comment: It gives the value as 0

Comment: Oh wait , forgot casting to int , try now.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing an considerable performance improvement with below approach. It might help you :)

```
       for each in list1:
            mykeys = each[1].keys()
            mylist = map(int,mykeys)
            common1 = set(mylist) & set(list2)
            common2 = set(mylist) & set(list3)
            if common1:
                tot_pos_probability = map(lambda ele: int(each[1][str(ele)][0])*list2[ele], common1)
                print sum(tot_pos_probability)
            if common2:
                tot_neg_probability = map(lambda ele: int(each[1][str(ele)][0])*list2[ele], common2)
                print sum(tot_neg_probability)
```